# Access selected text in another program in Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm going to be creating a `android application` to do that allows the user to access and uses the other application, and when he/she selects an text my application saves the text which is selected. it means I will create an application like `Google Translator`.
but I don't know where I start, and what's the correct key.

Answer (score -1):

> There is the [Google Translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/)

Google Translate API provides a simple programmatic interface for translating an arbitrary string into any supported language.

> There is also a [MyMemory API](https://mycodeandlife.wordpress.com/2013/02/05/android-tutorials-language-translator-app/)

Our REST API has been designed to be as easy as possible to implement. It is similar to the Google Translate API, extended with MyMemory specific parameters and lets you search and contribute to MyMemory archives.

> There is also a [tutorial available](https://mymemory.translated.net/doc/spec.php) on how to make a translator using Microsoft Translator:

Provides a Java wrapper around the Microsoft Translator API aka Bing Translator.

Comment: hope it helps you